# Object is possibly 'undefined' after validation in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Please see the following code. Do we have a convenient method to overcome this?

```js
interface IAnimal {
  type?: "animal" | "bird";
  body?: {
    legs?: number;
  };
}

// validate type and body.legs exists
function validator(animal:IAnimal){
  if(!animal || !animal.body|| !animal.body.legs){
    throw new Error('invalid');
  }
  console.log(animal.body.legs); // fine here
}

function foo(animal:IAnimal){
  validator(animal); // we called validation here

  console.log(animal.body.legs);
  //          ^^^^^^^^^^^ =========> Error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
}
```

I know this can be solved by the `!.`

```js
console.log(animal.body!.legs); // fine
```

But if this is a large function, we need to use this `!.` throughout the entire function even after the proper validation, which doesn't look good.
This error prone also. Is there any convenient way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Your interface `IAnimal`, sets `body` is `nullable` , the issue not come from your `validator` function. If `body` and `legs` are required, set these are required.

```
interface IAnimal {
  type?: "animal" | "bird";
  body: { // remove nullable mark
    legs: number; // ...
  };
}
```

Comment: Good. but in this case, we are altering the data model, which is not always possible. The ultimate aim is: 1) we have a data design in place. 2) **once it is validated, we should be good to go instead of repeatedly saying the tsc compiler that this variable is not undefined using `!.`**